# Format-patch неполный путь

Tags: git

При работе с Git после `commit` я выполняю `format-patch -1` и в файле патча у меня записываются неполные пути:

> src/app/etc/local.xml                             | 100 +++ 
>   .../cit/fonts/FontAwesome.otf          | Bin 0 -> 124988
>   bytes  .../citg/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot  | Bin 0 ->
>   76518 bytes  .../cityseing/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg  | 685
>   +++++++++++++++++++++  .../citing/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf  | Bin 0 -> 152796
>   bytes  .../citng/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff

Какой параметр, скорее всего, нужно прописать, чтобы выводились полные пути?

Comment: Полные пути чего? Гит и хранит полные пути относительно корня репозитория. Как иначе переносить изменения от одного разработчика к другому?

Comment: @Monk у меня пишет .../директория сизменениями, а я хочу dir with git/folder/folder/folder/dirwithchangers

Comment: Хм. Ну, как минимум есть ещё move, после которого патч должен быть рабочим, так что может это и правильный подход. Условно, если вы переименуете папку (только промежуточную?), то патч с полными путями сломается, а такой - будет работать

Comment: @Monk просто мой товарищ добавляет на Windows, а я работаю на Linux. И у него такие патчи на накатываются. А если переписать, то всё ок

Comment: Вот лучше такую информацию в вопрос вносить. Что патч сфорированный на ОС такой то с помощью такой то команды не применяется на другой ОС с такой то ошибкой если она есть.

Comment: Пусть товарищ на Windows освоит `git bash`.